# Is there a way to merge two IObservables such that if B finishes before A, it halts the result (but not vice-versa)?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have two `IObservable` sequences that will return at most one item before completing. I want to merge them, but while the first sequence will *usually* complete first, in rare cases may complete second. If it completes second, then I want to ignore its output.

```
Normal case:
A       1
B       -  2
Result  1  2

Rare, "slow A" case:
A       -  1
B       2
Result  2
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? I'm not aware of a way to prematurely end a merged sequence based on which `IObservable` triggered the last `OnNext`. The best solution I have is to `Select` and return a `Tuple` indicating which sequence the value came from, and simply ignoring everything after a "B" result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case, the following should work:

```
var combined = A.TakeUntil(B).Merge(B);
```

Comment: Ooh snap! :) Just like that.

Comment: It was the time you spent typing `IObservable<int>` instead of `var` :)

Comment: @MatthewFinlay, if `B` is a Cold observable, this will cause it to be fired twice, correct? And so I should created it with `.Publish().RefCount()` before initializing `combined`?

Comment: @JamesWorld, my follow-up question could be asked of you, since your answer was the same.

Comment: Yes indeed, you should if multiple subscriptions would be problematic - which is not *necessarily* the case. I wrote a bit about `.Publish().RefCount()` here: http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=144

Comment: @moswald, that is correct - if B is a cold observable, it will fire twice, unless you use `.Publish().RefCount()`. But if either of these are a cold observable, then the idea of one coming before the other doesn't really work any more.

Answer (score 3):

If we have two variables for our streams `IObservable<int> a,b;` then:

```
IObservable<int> result = a.TakeUntil(b).Merge(b);
```